# Regex replacing more than I want

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to delete from the `body` element only one class which starts with `demo-XXX` where `xxx` can be any character and without a fix length.

So I can have something like this in the body

```
<body classs="bye demo-hello water">
```

I was using this regex `/\b\s?demo-.*\b/g` like so:

```
$("body")[0].className = $("body")[0].className.replace(/\b\s?demo-.*\b/g, '');
```

But it is removing as well all the classes after `demo-XXX`, such as `water`:

```
<body classs="bye">
```

Comment: Split the className string by space, then loop through to remove anything you don't want (by testing against a regex), join whatever that is left and assign it back.

Comment: Can you show your remove function?

Comment: When you learned regular expressions, didn't you learn that quantifiers are greedy by default?

Comment: @Barmar yep, but I though the `\b` option was separating words or something like that. *\b allows you to perform a "whole words only"*

Comment: `\b` matches a word separator. It doesn't have to be the first one. So the greedy quantifier will go until the last word separator.

Comment: @chsdk the `replace` you can see there is the internal javascript function.

Comment: @Alvaro ok then, so you can try the regex in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude space usintg `^\s` and look for 1 or more characters so use `+` instead of `*`

```
$("body")[0].className =$("body")[0].className.replace(/\b\s?demo-[^\s]+\b/g,'');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m26hgw2g/10/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do it this way as said by @nhahtdh

```
$('body').attr('class', function(_, cls){
   return cls.split(/\s+/).filter(function(x){  // split
       return x.indexOf("demo-") !== 0; // filter out unwanted values
   }).join(" "); // join the array and return it
});
```

If you want regex solution, you could do

```
$('body').attr('class', function(_, cls){
   return cls.replace(/\bdemo-\S+/g,"");
});
```

Comment: That's more complex than a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
\b\s?demo-[a-zA-Z0-9]+\b
```

Use this.`.` will consume all before detecing `\b`.